# Postgresql greatly underestimate returned rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-optimization

I got an issue with Postgresql greatly underestimating number of rows returned by a join between CTE and a table. The xfactor is about 42 and I think that this leads Postgres to choose nested loop.
As you can see in `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, aggregating consume nearly 100% of the total time.
The most interesting thing is that I've tried to add another query level to perform the sum afterwards and it is decreasing time from 33s to 6s.
I think that nested-loop is joining table in such a bad way that aggregating the output is a pain for Postgres. Or maybe I'm missing something important ?

**Tables** (each one containing 50k rows) :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.forme_iris
(
    code_iris character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    geometry geometry,
    CONSTRAINT forme_iris_pkey PRIMARY KEY (code_iris)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.dl_rawdata_recensement
(
    iris character varying(200)
    pop_0_14_ans_en_2016_princ character varying(223),
    pop_15_29_ans_en_2016_princ character varying(224),
    pop_30_44_ans_en_2016_princ character varying(225),
    pop_45_59_ans_en_2016_princ character varying(226),
    pop_60_74_ans_en_2016_princ character varying(220),
    pop_75_ans_ou_plus_en_2016_princ character varying(228),
    CONSTRAINT dl_rawdata_recensement_pkey PRIMARY KEY (iris)
)
```

**Covering Index :**

```
CREATE INDEX dl_rawdata_recensement_cvg_idx1
    ON public.dl_rawdata_recensement USING btree
    (iris COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(pop_0_14_ans_en_2016_princ, pop_15_29_ans_en_2016_princ, pop_30_44_ans_en_2016_princ, pop_45_59_ans_en_2016_princ, pop_60_74_ans_en_2016_princ, pop_75_ans_ou_plus_en_2016_princ, pop_15_ans_ou_plus_hommes_en_2016_cplt, pop_15_ans_ou_plus_femmes_en_2016_cplt, pop_0_14_ans_en_2016_princ)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

**Whole query**:

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ST_SetSrid(ST_GeomFromGeoJson('{geometry}'), 4326) AS geom
)
SELECT SUM(pourcentage * (pop_0_14_ans_en_2016_princ + pop_15_29_ans_en_2016_princ + pop_30_44_ans_en_2016_princ + pop_45_59_ans_en_2016_princ + pop_60_74_ans_en_2016_princ + pop_75_ans_ou_plus_en_2016_princ)) total_population,
       SUM(pourcentage * pop_0_14_ans_en_2016_princ) total_0_14,
       SUM(pourcentage * pop_15_29_ans_en_2016_princ) total_15_29,
       SUM(pourcentage * pop_30_44_ans_en_2016_princ) total_30_44,
       SUM(pourcentage * pop_45_59_ans_en_2016_princ) total_45_59,
       SUM(pourcentage * pop_60_74_ans_en_2016_princ) total_60_74,
       SUM(pourcentage * pop_75_ans_ou_plus_en_2016_princ) total_75
FROM (SELECT (ST_Area(ST_Intersection(iris.geometry, cte.geom)) / ST_Area(iris.geometry)) AS pourcentage, 
             code_iris
      FROM forme_iris iris
      JOIN cte
      ON ST_Intersects(iris.geometry, cte.geom)) AS a
JOIN public.dl_rawdata_recensement population
ON population.iris = a.code_iris
```

**Subquery concerned by the nested-loop**:

```
SELECT (ST_Area(ST_Intersection(iris.geometry, cte.geom)) / ST_Area(iris.geometry)) AS pourcentage, 
       code_iris
FROM forme_iris iris
JOIN cte
ON ST_Intersects(iris.geometry, cte.geom)
```

I've vacuumed + analyzed both table before performing the request. Is Postgres still missing some statistics ?

**PostgreSQL version**: PostgreSQL 11.12 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit

**Postgis version**: 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`: https://explain.depesz.com/s/sjON

Thanks !

Comment: How fast is this query without the aggregates?

Comment: 5.5 seconds, nearly what I got when I put aggregate on a higher level. The query is bottleneck by nested loop now. EXPLAIN ANALYZE : https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/rtk

Comment: Dalibo is good at turning execution plans into pretty-looking garbage.  Please collect it again as `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, FORMAT TEXT)` and either post it here as formatted text, or host it at https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: here it is : https://explain.depesz.com/s/sjON

Comment: Isn't the one you showed us already the one that has another query level to compute the sum afterwards?

Comment: No that's another one, I can make an update if you want (but not right now I'm out of time)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bottleneck is in postgis, in the calculation of ST_Area and ST_Intersection with your presumably very large and complex literal geography value.  I don't think the misestimate has anything to do with it--those calculations will be done the same way no matter how many rows it thinks there will be.

Perhaps one way of writing the query causes those calculations to be done over and over, and another way of writing doesn't.  But without seeming both of those queries at the same time, it is hard to say more.  And I don't think PostgreSQL's decision to re-compute versus re-use is driven by row estimates.

Comment: I should've tried before but you're right, when I'm only requesting for all intersections, it's taking almost the same time. Is there a faster way to compute all intersection ?

Maybe if I was able to split my giant geometry into smaller one and use index on it during run time, it could speed up the calculation of intersection ?
To give you the main problem, I need the list of all intersected iris (small area) and their percentage of inclusion into the giant geometry, knowing that iris are 200x smaller than the giant geometry.

Comment: I don't know much about the inner working of postgis.  There is a gis.stackexchange.com that might be able to offer some insight there.